# Having an issue with mutate, last and elseif - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to group by some records and then if the last blood (CRP) marker for that record is <8, I want to print NA for the whole record, otherwise I want to leave the entries the same. I'm nearly there, but I have a glitch...

input:

```
structure(list(record_id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "c", "c"), relative_admission_day = c(-2, 
-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0), troponin = c(NA, NA, NA, 30, NA, NA, NA
), CRP = c(NA, 5.3, NA, 179, NA, NA, 166), ferritin = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 105, NA, NA, 199)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), groups = structure(list(
    record_id = c("101-1", "101-10", "103-15"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:3, 4:5, 6:7), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Desired output:

```
  record_id relative_admission_day troponin   CRP ferritin  CRP2
  <chr>                      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 a                             -2       NA  NA         NA    NA
2 a                             -1       NA   5.3       NA    NA
3 a                              0       NA  NA         NA    NA
4 b                             -1       30 179        105   179
5 b                              0       NA  NA         NA    NA
6 c                             -1       NA  NA         NA    NA
7 c                              0       NA 166        199   166
```

My code is:

```
input %>% group_by(record_id) %>% mutate(CRP2=ifelse(last(na.omit(CRP) < 8), NA, CRP))
```

Failed output:

```
structure(list(record_id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "c", "c"), relative_admission_day = c(-2, 
-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0), troponin = c(NA, NA, NA, 30, NA, NA, NA
), CRP = c(NA, 5.3, NA, 179, NA, NA, 166), ferritin = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 105, NA, NA, 199), CRP2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 179, 179, NA, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), groups = structure(list(
    record_id = c("101-1", "101-10", "103-15"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:3, 4:5, 6:7), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I'm getting the correct `CRP2` result for `a`. For `b` the filtering is working but it's printing the value twice, and for `c` it's not working at all. If I remove the `na.omit` bit then `c` extracts the value, but I need the `na.omit` bit for `b` to work!

I'm at a bit of a loss!

Comment: You should use `if`/`else` rather than `ifelse` - `if (last(na.omit(CRP)) < 8) NA else CRP`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thanks! It works... however, I've realised it fails when there's only one entry for a record and it's a NA..

Comment: @RitchieSacramento `input %>% group_by(record_id) %>% mutate(troponin=if(last(na.omit(troponin) < 14) | all(is.na(troponin))) NA else(troponin))` That should do it right?

Comment: Parentheses are not quite right in your attempt - it should be `if (last(na.omit(troponin)) < 14 | all(is.na(troponin))) NA else troponin`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramen Thanks, though I seem to get the same result with my code... but I'll use yours as I'm sure mine would cause error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Does this cover what you are asking?

```
input %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>% 
  mutate(group_min = min(na.omit(CRP))) %>%
  mutate(CRP2 = ifelse(group_min < 8,NA, CRP)) %>%
  select(-group_min)
```